# Access trade/position history regardless of strategy?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm an expert metatrader programmer (MQL5) trying to get up to speed on PineScript.

I don't see a way to access trade history regardless of if order(s) were placed by a strategy.  (such as having a script enumerate trades taken manually by a user)

Is this even possible?

I've reviewed the documentation extensively, and although I'm still learning the execution model etc, the only thing I've seen is in the strategy{} namespace and that seems to be limited to trades taken by the running strategy?

Comment: There is no yet possibility to get pending orders, you can access only trades by 
strategy.closed_trades.* and strategy.open_trades.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I really like the power of Pine Script to do things with a few lines of code that took C++ levels of coding to accomplish in MQL5, but the trade-off of capability is frustrating.  Thanks again!